# Generate PDF base64 encode from iText in Java

Tags: java, base64, itext

How can I encode a PDF file generated in iText to base64?

This is my (java) code

**App.java**

```
public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    // step 1
    Document document = new Document();
    // step 2
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("pdf.pdf"));
    // step 3
    document.open();

    String str = "<html><head></head><body style=\"font-size:12.0pt; font-family:Times New Roman\">"
            + "<a href='http://www.rgagnon.com/howto.html'><b>Real's HowTo</b></a>" + "<h1>Show your support</h1>"
            + "<p>It DOES cost a lot to produce this site - in ISP storage and transfer fees</p>"
            + "<p>TEST POLSKICH ZNAKÓW: \u0104\u0105\u0106\u0107\u00d3\u00f3\u0141\u0142\u0179\u017a\u017b\u017c\u017d\u017e\u0118\u0119</p>"
            + "<hr/>"
            + "<p>the huge amounts of time it takes for one person to design and write the actual content.</p>"
            + "<p>If you feel that effort has been useful to you, perhaps you will consider giving something back?</p>"
            + "<p>Donate using PayPal\u017d</p>" + "<p>Contributions via PayPal are accepted in any amount</p>"
            + "<p><br/><table border='1'><tr><td>Java HowTo</td></tr><tr>"
            + "<td style='background-color:red;'>Javascript HowTo</td></tr>"
            + "<tr><td>Powerbuilder HowTo</td></tr></table></p>" + "</body></html>";

    XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    worker.parseXHtml(writer, document, is, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

    // step 5
    document.close();

    System.out.println("PDF Created!");

}
```

}

iText library dependencies (xmlworker e itextpdf)

**Pom file:**

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Im stuck, any help is welcome.

Comment: Both versions must be the same.

Comment: Change the version number to 5.5.12.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same thing and this is how I did it. I used apache.commons libraries to encode and to read file contents into a byte array. Hope this helps.

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

File file = new File("test.pdf");

  // write your html template to the file and close the document.
byte[] pdf =FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(pdf); 
      //or byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(file.getBytes());
```

This was done in groovy, write appropriate code according your requirment.

Comment: maybe it can be of help if you put some more details and some code too. Otherwise this cannot be so useful. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Sorry, I hit save by mistake before iIcould complete typing my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard java.util.Base64:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);

byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
bytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes);
Files.write(Paths.get("pdf.pdf"), bytes);
```